# using customer rate limited spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I have requirement to route calls (POST JSON) to different endpoints, based on customer. In this process, based on customer's implementation and capacity to handle requests, basically would like to rate limit per customer/route.

Using Spring Cloud Gateway am able to successfully route, but still unable to figure out how to implement custom rate limiter (or wire resilience4j implementation). Only examples= available is Redis based (for distributed management, which is NOT a requirement yet in my case, so wanted to avoid extra overhead).

Using Spring Boot 2.7.x, JDK 11. Appreciate any suggestion/comments.
Edit - wrote a sample app and committed to github
https://github.com/jobas2007/spring-cloud-rate-limit